# Как в большом цикле правильно генерировать canvas?

Tags: javascript

В цикле работает очень медленно, если вместо 3000 написать 100000, он совсем зависнет

На рабочем сайте иногда выдает ошибку `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Как можно ускорить такой код?

```js
let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx;
for(let i = 0; i < 3000; i++){
  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Ошибку `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` выдает этот код
`Math.min(...data.map(e => e.price));`

Почему он ограничивает меня?

Comment: А зачем проводить одну и ту же линию 3000 раз? Или, что у вас на самом деле происходит в цикле?) Может удалили, не считая важным. А в приведенном коде единственный минус - получение `ctx` внутри цикла. Нужно вынести его. `strokе()` тоже можно делать один раз в конце, вне цикла - в зависимости от кода.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, это просто пример, по образцу взят из своего кода, вся суть в цикле

Comment: Но в цикле не увеличивается call stack size)

Comment: @vp_arth, добавил в конце вопроса причину, только что узнал на какой код эта ошибка вызывает

Comment: используйте другие методы для поиска минимума в длинных массивах без разворачивания их в параметры

Comment: Да массив может и не длинный, просто конкретному вызову map(или Math.min) не хватило места в стеке из-за внешней рекурсии

Comment: @vp_arth почему думаете что тут имеется рекурсия?

Comment: Сложно без рекурсии заполнить стек вызовов))

Comment: @vp_arth ну это да ) сегодня что-то как раз попадалось на enSO что max(...arr) на больших массивах что-то про стек выдает. проверил, не выдает ) вернее выдает ожидаемое, что число аргументов превышено.

Comment: а, про node.js там было https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986992/1216425, но что-то запомнилось ) но вероятно чел там тоже попутал сообщения об ошибке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно запускать длинный синхронный код. Для отрисовки кадров используйте requestAnimationFrame.

```js
let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let i = 0, N = 3000;
const draw = () => {
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
  ctx.stroke();

  i++;
  if (i < N) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  } else {
    console.log(`${N} iterations are finished`)
  }
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```